# How do I bake custom Normal into a normal map?

Tags: texture-baking

How do I bake custom Normal into a normal map?

In order to use custom Normal, you must turn on auto-smooth, which is very slow (FPS drops to about 1/3 with EEVEE animation).

I am looking for a way to maintain a high FPS while keeping the flat face of the animation style using custom Normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By baking selected-to-active normals, from a mesh with custom normals to a smooth shaded mesh without custom normals.  Selected-to-active baking is well described elsewhere on this site, but I'll go over the entire process anyways:

[image]

1. Duplicate your object.  Delete custom normals on your duplicate.  Disable autosmooth on your duplicate.
2. Assign your duplicate a material.  In that material, create a non-color image texture node with a new image.  Make sure that image texture node is the actively selected node group in that material.
3. Set up your bake.  Set rendering engine to cycles, set it to bake normals (tangent or object space, your choice, tangent is necessary for deforming geometry while object is better for non-deforming), set it to selected-to-active, and use a very small ray extrusion value.  In the picture above, the objects are placed side by side only for visualization; the two objects should actually be right on top of each other.
4. In 3D view, select your original, then shift select your duplicate, such that your duplicate is the active selection.  Hit the bake button.  Save your baked image, which is your normal map for a version of the mesh without custom normals or autosmooth:

[image]

On the left, we're using a normal map; on the right, we're using our original custom normals.

Comment: It worked!
Thank you so much for your thorough description!

Answer (score 0):

I can do this by baking a world space normal and then baking it back to tangent space normal. I don't think this will cause the strange problems that sometimes occur when baking to the target object.

Baking back to tangent space normals can be simply achieved by changing the *Normal Map* node to *Object Mode*.